# Getting an attribute from a child class - is this possible?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to get the attribute of a child class in Python 3?

This doesn't work:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        print(vars(self))


class Bar(Foo):
    example_attribute = "baz"


test = Bar()
# prints {}
# I want it to print {"example_attribute": "baz"}
```

Comment: Your example doesn’t correspond to the question in the title and the post. Can you clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your attribute is a *class* attribute. You can get it with:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        print(vars(self.__class__))
```

result:

```
{'__module__': '__main__', 'example_attribute': 'baz', '__doc__': None}
```

if the attribute was an *instance* attribute, you would have to call the parent `__init__` *after* you have defined it. Something like:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        print(vars(self))

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        self.example_attribute = "baz"
        Foo.__init__(self)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the answer above but with a **main** to execute an instance of Bar()

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        print(vars(self.__class__))

class Bar(Foo):
    example_attribute = "baz"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = Bar()
```